# Reduce Pandas Memory Footprint?

Tags: python, pandas, memory, dataframe, categorical-data

Just fired up a Jupyter terminal and loaded up an Excel file (~12MB) into a Pandas Dataframe

**Before Loading file:**

```
>> import resource
>> print 'Memory usage: %s (Mb)' % (resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss/1024)
```

> Memory usage: 40 (Mb)

**After Loading file into a Pandas Dataframe:**

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> df = pd.read_excel('/var/www/temp_test_files/stackoverflow_survey_2016.xlsx')
>> print 'Memory usage: %s (Mb)' % (resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss/1024)
```

> Memory usage: 193 (Mb)

Why is it that a 12Mb file when loaded in pandas, occupies 150mb more than 12 times its actual size in memory ?

Detailed breakdown of the column dtypes below. i'm guessing the object dtypes are allocated more memory than the actual usage of the column?

```
>> df.info(memory_usage=True)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 56030 entries, 0 to 56029
Data columns (total 57 columns):
collector                   56030 non-null object
country                     55528 non-null object
un_subregion                55313 non-null object
so_region                   55390 non-null object
age_range                   55727 non-null object
age_midpoint                55336 non-null float64
gender                      55586 non-null object
self_identification         54202 non-null object
occupation                  49519 non-null object
occupation_group            46934 non-null object
experience_range            49520 non-null object
experience_midpoint         49520 non-null float64
salary_range                46121 non-null object
salary_midpoint             41742 non-null float64
programming_ability         46982 non-null float64
employment_status           49576 non-null object
industry                    40110 non-null object
company_size_range          39932 non-null object
team_size_range             39962 non-null object
women_on_team               39808 non-null object
remote                      40118 non-null object
job_satisfaction            40110 non-null object
job_discovery               40027 non-null object
commit_frequency            46598 non-null object
hobby                       46673 non-null object
dogs_vs_cats                45239 non-null object
desktop_os                  46451 non-null object
unit_testing                46657 non-null object
rep_range                   46143 non-null object
visit_frequency             46154 non-null object
why_learn_new_tech          46145 non-null object
education                   44955 non-null object
open_to_new_job             44380 non-null object
new_job_value               43658 non-null object
job_search_annoyance        42851 non-null object
interview_likelihood        42263 non-null object
star_wars_vs_star_trek      34398 non-null object
agree_tech                  42662 non-null object
agree_notice                42755 non-null object
agree_problemsolving        42659 non-null object
agree_diversity             42505 non-null object
agree_adblocker             42627 non-null object
agree_alcohol               42692 non-null object
agree_loveboss              42096 non-null object
agree_nightcode             42613 non-null object
agree_legacy                42382 non-null object
agree_mars                  42685 non-null object
important_variety           42628 non-null object
important_control           42572 non-null object
important_sameend           42531 non-null object
important_newtech           42604 non-null object
important_buildnew          42538 non-null object
important_buildexisting     42580 non-null object
important_promotion         42483 non-null object
important_companymission    42529 non-null object
important_wfh               42582 non-null object
important_ownoffice         42538 non-null object
dtypes: float64(4), object(53)
memory usage: 24.8+ MB
None
```

Are there any "best practice" methods to reduce the actual memory footprint of a Pandas data frame ?

- Tinkering with the dtypes ?
- Categoricals ?

Comment: So, most of your `dtypes` are `object`. That means the underlying `numpy` array is of `object` dtype. Thus, the memory usage is only for the *PyObject* pointers in your arrays. But then, Python has to store the actual data somewhere. Likely, these are mostly string fields, yes?

Comment: yeah they are indeed string fields for the most part

Comment: I'm not an expert but you may find these two links from Wes McKinney helpful: https://www.slideshare.net/wesm/practical-medium-data-analytics-with-python  and  http://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that a 12Mb file when loaded in pandas, occupies 150mb more
>   than 12 times its actual size in memory ?

That 12MB Excel file is in compressed format. The actual size of raw data in the file could be 5 or 10 times that. You can verify that if you simply rename the file to .zip and extract its contents.

> Are there any "best practice" methods to reduce the actual memory
>   footprint of a Pandas data frame ? Tinkering with the dtypes ? Categoricals ?

Yes, using `dtypes`, `category` data types, and downcasting are the best methods.

Since most of your columns are of type string, your best option to reduce memory is to use `dtypes` to specify explicit `category` types for low cardinality columns. 
E.g. country, region, gender, status.

All 4 of your `float64` columns can also be reduced to unsigned 32-bit data types (or lower: like age, salary)